# How to define rule for JSON body Mockoon

Tags: mocking, mockoon

I have a simple `GET` method in Postman:

```json
{
    "requestId": 200
}
```

For simplicity I wanted to return 200 response on `requestId` 200 and 400 on `requestId` 400 and I'm not able to do that in Mockoon 6.1.0.

I have 2 responses for one route with a rules

```
Body $.requestId equals 400
```

(value 200/400 is different if rule for first request and for second)

Rules from JSON file:

```json
{
          "rules": [
            {
              "target": "body",
              "modifier": "$.requestId",
              "value": "200",
              "invert": false,
              "operator": "equals"
            }
          ],

          "rules": [
            {
              "target": "body",
              "modifier": "$.requestId",
              "value": "400",
              "invert": false,
              "operator": "equals"
            }
          ],

}
```

[image]

I always get response 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to the fact that your `requestId` field is a number. It appears the "equals" rule plays well with strings but not numbers.

As a workaround you can select "regex" in the comparator list.

Comment: Note: I opened an issue to improve this (https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/issues/1247)

Comment: Is there any way to define the request body schema in Mockoon UI?

Comment: No, Mockoon is an API mocking tool first, not an API design tool. So, we don't really take care of the request.